# How save chr(931) in a file on windows?

Tags: python, codec

```
x = open("file.txt",'w')
s = chr(931) # 'Σ'
x.write(s)
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03a3' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Even if I save the char 'Σ' in Windows txt-editor under code UTF-8 and then open in python the return will be 'ï»¿Î£' and not what I expect Σ.

I don't understand why python interpret the sign wrong because it's utf-8 or is this a problem in windows?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solve the problem by saving as bytes instead of string

```
def save_byte():
    x = open("file.txt",'wb')
    s = chr(931) # 'Σ'
    s = s.encode()
    x.write(s)
    x.close()
```

outout:
Σ

Comment: No, completly wrong. Python 2 treatment of strings and bytes as one entity was broken by design. Now it is sensible. Specify the encoding when opening the file instead.

Python uses unicode to represent characters internally. UTF-8 is an encoding for unicode characters. These are to different things. The sentence "utf-8 is apparently not every time utf-8 in python" makes no sense at all.

Comment: I posted an answer

Comment: ok MaxNoe but then explain me why I can't write the sign Σ which is type of string with simple open("text.txt", 'w')?

Comment: Because your default system encoding seems to be cp1252, which cannot represent GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA

Answer (score 1):

Your default encoding seems to be cp1252, not utf-8.
You need to specify the encoding, to be sure it's utf-8.

#### this works fine:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('Σ')
```

#### this raises your error:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w', encoding='cp1252') as f:
    f.write('Σ')
```